# What is the song in the first episode called?

Tags: music, ookami-kakushi

After a short opening segment to the series there was this opening song. After searching for the opening for a bit I found that it was not the same song.

So which song is used and what is it called?

Comment: Maybe you can try recording a portion of it and using music recognition apps to find its name? Also, have you tried searching for full OSTs?

Comment: @user1306322 I am a real leak when it comes to that. I would have no clue how to. Then again, the song sounds familiar. As if used in another anime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With user1306322's advice I attempted some searching. And came to the conclusion it was Toki No Mukou Maboroshi No Sora - FictionJunction.

The song I originally kept finding was the opening song of the visual novel instead of the song used in the anime. And the fact I found to be familiar is most likely due to [Yuki Kajiura](http://myanimelist.net/people/5077/Yuki_Kajiura), which has allot of anime songs on her name that I watched.

Comment: Note: Yuki Kajiura is the composer for FictionJunction. She's not a singer.